# How can I controll the number of UIPicker non-selected rows?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, uipicker

Here I have a picker with a Textfield above;however,these non-selected data row will cover my textfield lead me into the situation of unable to click the textfield to input data, thus I'd like to reduce the number of non-selected row appearance.Yes indeed I could lift up the position of textfield,but the visual effect will be unbalanced.Is any other way to go?

Comment: set the Frame for your picker.

Comment: I had add frame in my pickerview (which will be added into my popover view), but it can just move the position for y position? any idea?

Comment: play with its "content" size.

Comment: if you are not so strict to stick with UIPIcker, do you mind using another custom control that enables you the granular control over the selectiontoo. ??

Comment: You can use the `WYPopOverController` which is intelligent enough to figure out where you have tapped so which direction should it pop to, giving you an alternative to un-hide the `UItextField`. [WYPopOverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController)

Comment: I think I will just use uipicker,cuz for this part to third party controler is not ecomically for my case,But still tanks for your advise ^^